# How to change html order in News Flash Advanced layouts?

Tags: template-override, module-display, joomla-3.6, jhtml

So, I'm trying to make a testimonials page and I'm using Joomla 3.64 with the News Flash Advanced Module. The site is using Theme1498 by Template Monster. I believe that there was some custom work done on the theme, but I'm not in touch with whoever designed it.

I want to change the order in which the html is being displayed on a specific page, so basically I want a page specific layout. What I want to achieve is putting the title below the item's intro text. I think what I need to do is create an override for the layout, but I'm not sure which file to mess with. Within the theme's html->mod_articles_news_advanced there are the following files:

```
 _custom_item.php
 _news_item.php
 _projects_item.php
 custom.php
 masonry.php
 news.php
 projects.php
```

From poking around in the files, I think I need to modify one of the files preceded by the underscore, but that is as far I have gotten so far.

So how do the _item.php files relate to the layout files? When you go to the Advanced tab on the module, the Alternative layouts only correspond to the files without the underscore prefix, but the files with the underscore prefix are the only ones which look like they contain the html that I want to change.

I assume I need a custom _item.php file and probably a custom layout as well, but not sure how these files relate or how to go about getting these changes only on a single page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the _item.php files contained the html for the individual items, and the layout files themselves handled the placement of multiple items on the page itself. The layout file itself contained a function `require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath` which pointed back to the item file. I copied and created custom item and layout files with the getLayoutPath function pointing to the new custom item file and that solved my problem.